# How to use array of ranges from a custom function into google sheets query

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell equation as follows:

```
QUERY(
 {'Match 1 - August 24, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 1 - September 5, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 3 - August 24, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 1 - August 31, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 2 - August 31, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 1 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 2 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 3 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 4 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 5 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 6 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;'Match 7 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100}, "select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1")
```

It works fine but it requires a lot of manual work as sheets are being added. I'm hoping to get a better way of populating the array so I created a custom function:

```
function getMatchSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var out = new Array()
  ss.getSheets().forEach(function(val){
    if(val.getName().startsWith('Match')){
      out.push("'"+val.getSheetName()+"'!$A$3:$D$100;");
    }
  });
  return out;
};
```

Using it in a cell shows the expected values in different rows:

```
'Match 2 - August 24, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 1 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 2 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 3 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 4 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 5 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 6 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 7 - September 7, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 2 - August 31, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 1 - August 31, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 3 - August 24, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 1 - August 24, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
'Match 1 - September 5, 2023'!$A$3:$D$100;
```

I was hoping I could use that in the first equation like this:

```
QUERY(
 getMatchSheets(), "select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1")
```

It gives a not too helpful error:

```
Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col3
```

Any thoughts?

I've tried multiple answers but none seems to work for me.

1. [How to use a custom function in a Google Sheets QUERY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71384251/how-to-use-a-custom-function-in-a-google-sheets-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach: Once the tabs list is populated in a column, use the below formula. Also remove the `semicolon` in this part of your script here `!$A$3:$D$100;` prior to using the formula*

```js
=let(Σ,reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(A:A,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,indirect(c)))),
     query(Σ,"select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))
```

[image]

Comment: This did the trick but I would love to understand what's happening.

Comment: You can just test the *reduce* part of the formula separately to get a picture `=reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(A:A,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,indirect(c))))` To put it simple, *reduce* is pulling one tab data at a time and stacking them one over the other to create a collated data of all the tabs upon which the query function will then be applied.